# How do I disable the object definition window in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, if I Ctl+click or press F12 on an object defined elsewhere in the file, the focus is moved to that object, but additionally a window opens up showing me exactly what I'm already trying to look at except in a smaller window than I would normally be viewing the object definition. If I instead press Alt+F12, this object definition window opens without moving my focus to the object.

In the case of pressing Alt+F12, this functionality could potentially be useful since it saves me from having to navigate from the code I'm working with. However, in the case of Ctl+click or F12, both navigating away from the code I'm working with and displaying the object definition in a smaller window is not helpful and I want to disable it.

Here is an image of what I'm trying to describe when using Ctl+click or F12:
[image: VS Code Object Definition Window]

How do I disable this? I would prefer to only disable the functionality that both shows the window and navigates away, but would settle for disabling showing the window entirely.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been addressed in version 1.26.1 of VS Code.

Comment: How did you solved that problem?